# Docker Volumes and Binds

Tags: docker

I have below scenario while using docker container:

1. I have created a "Dell Boomi" container using docker run command
   (on Red Hat Linux using -v) and the container is up and running.

> docker run -p 8092:9090 -h dockeratom05 -v
>   /home/ec2-user/boomi_docker:/var/boomi -e
>   URL=https://platform.boomi.com -e BOOMI_USERNAME= -e
>   BOOMI_PASSWORD= -e BOOMI_ATOMNAME=dockeratom05 -e
>   BOOMI_CONTAINERNAME=dockeratom05 -e BOOMI_ACCOUNTID= -e
>   PROXY_HOST= -e PROXY_USERNAME= -e PROXY_PASSWORD= -e PROXY_PORT= -e
>   DOCKERUID= -e SYMLINKS_DIR= -e ATOM_LOCALHOSTID=dockeratom05 -e
>   INSTALL_TOKEN= -e INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY=/var/boomi --name
>   dockeratom05 -d -t boomi/atom:20.02.0

2. After a while, there is a need to access a shared folder available
   in a different windows server.

> Ex: C:\win_shared_drive

3. I have created a mount point in Red Hat Linux with below command:

> mount -t cifs -o username=
>   ///win_shared_drive
>   /home/ec2-user/boomi_docker/Atom_dockeratom05/win_share

In the above command '/home/ec2-user/boomi_docker/' is the binding I have used while running the docker container in step 'a'.

4. Within the container, I can see the newly created shared directory
   and I am able to create the files in this directory inside the
   container.

However I am these newly created files are not available in the host system .i.e on Red Hat Linux.

Is this the expected behavior?

What needs to be done to see the newly created files in the host system?

Regards,
Sena

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **consistent** switch with your host volume which will bring the change immediately on your docker host. Check out the following link. 
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs-caching/

```
docker run -p 8092:9090 -h dockeratom05 \
-v /home/ec2-user/boomi_docker:/var/boomi:consistent \
-e URL=https://platform.boomi.com \
-e BOOMI_USERNAME= \
-e BOOMI_PASSWORD= \
-e BOOMI_ATOMNAME=dockeratom05 \
-e BOOMI_CONTAINERNAME=dockeratom05 \
-e BOOMI_ACCOUNTID= \
-e PROXY_HOST= \
-e PROXY_USERNAME= \
-e PROXY_PASSWORD= \
-e PROXY_PORT= \
-e DOCKERUID= \
-e SYMLINKS_DIR= \
-e ATOM_LOCALHOSTID=dockeratom05 \
-e INSTALL_TOKEN= \
-e INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY=/var/boomi \
--name dockeratom05 \
-d -t \
boomi/atom:20.02.0
```

And as you've shared your scenario of accesing these files by creating a mount point. Just make sure you don't write to the same file simultaneously to avoid data corruption.

Comment: Thank you Shakaib for the inputs.

Comment: Does this input resolve the issue which you was facing?